# Error cannot resolve method setText

Tags: android

hello why i am having this error?

> cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String[])

```
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, null,true);
        }
        Product product = getItem(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProduct);
        TextView textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        textName.setText(product.getName());

        TextView textPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        textPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `Product` class in question .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a string array on textview (`setText(java.lang.String[])` )which is not possible so either use index to set particular value

```
textPrice.setText(product.getPrice()[0]);
```

of convert array into string

```
textPrice.setText(Arrays.toString(i1)); // not recommended
```

Note : There is no overloaded [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) method which can accept a string array

Comment: Thank you Brotherr.. it worked.. i am getting error anymore.. thks

Comment: @Edgar I am glad that I could help, happy coding